# nginx - How rewrite directive works on location matching together with flags?

Tags: nginx

Should following nginx config be dead cycle?

```
location / {
    # url rewrites
    rewrite ^/(.*).jsp$ /$1.html last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

According to doc it seems should, but in test it seems works the same as:

```
rewrite ^/(.*).jsp$ /$1.html break;
```

---

### **@Update**

About `last`, nginx doc says:

> it start a search for a new location that matches the rewritten URL.

**The questions are:**

- What does that mean? Does it means to search for the next `location` directive?
- And what if there is only 1 `location` where the current `last` resides, should it stop or .. ?

Comment: Why would it be an infinite loop? First you change your `something.jsp` to `something.html`, then start once again from the beginning of the location (because of the `last` flag and presuming there is only one location) and go straight to `try_files`, skipping the `rewrite` (because the URI is now *.html, not *.jsp).

Comment: @IvanTsirulev Thanks, I updated the question, can you help with that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To explain this, let's take a look at this example configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {                   #  Location #1
        root /some/path;
    }

    location ~ ^/(foo|bar|baz) {   #  Location #2

        rewrite ^/foo /bar;        #  Rewrite rule #1
        rewrite ^/bar /baz break;  #  Rewrite rule #2
        rewrite ^/baz /qux last;   #  Rewrite rule #3
        rewrite ^/qux /foo;        #  Rewrite rule #4

        root /another/path;
    }
}
```

1. What happens if we are trying to open `http://localhost/foo` in a
   browser is this:

   Nginx parses the request, gets the URI part (`/foo`) and then looks
   for all the locations that match this requested URI. In this case
   both locations match the URI, but since `Location #2` is defined
   with a regular expression, Nginx will choose it over `Location #1`,
   or in other words, will make this location the request context. You
   can find some info on the location priorities in the
   [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

   Now that the location is determined, Nginx starts executing all the
   rewrite directives found in it one by one.

   After the `Rewrite rule #1` is executed the URI is changed from
   `/foo` to `/bar` and Nginx proceeds with execution of the next
   rewrite directive, which is the `Rewrite rule #2`.

   After the `Rewrite rule #2` is executed the URI is once again
   changed, this time from `/bar` to `/baz`. And since the `break` flag
   is used Nginx won't execute the rest rewrite directives in this
   location. So neither the `Rewrite rule #3` nor `Rewrite rule #4`
   will be executed this time.

   As a result, `/another/path/baz` will be shown in the browser.

   The same file will be served if we request `http://localhost/bar`
   directly. Only in that case `Rewrite rule #1` will not be executed
   (because `/bar` does not match `^/foo`).
2. Now if we try to open `http://localhost/baz` the process will go
   like this:

   The `Location #2` will be chosen as the context because it is of a
   higher priority and matches the request. Both the `Rewrite rule #1`
   and `Rewrite rule #2` will be ignored, because `/baz` does not match
   either `^/foo` or `^/bar`.

   The `break` flag of `Rewrite rule #2` will be ignored along with the
   rule itself, because flags affect the process only when URI is being
   rewritten by the rule to which the flag belongs.

   The `Rewrite rule #3` matches the URI and so it will be executed.
   The rule changes the URI from `/baz` to `/qux` and then the whole
   process is interrupted because the `last` flag kicks in. What it
   does is basically tells Nginx to stop processing the request and
   start from the very beginning but this time using the rewritten URI.

   So Nginx starts looking for a suitable location once again, but this
   time the URI is `/qux`, not `/baz`. And since `Location #2` does not
   match `/qux`, `Location #1` is chosen as the request context. And so
   `/some/path/qux` is served (pay attention to the path).

   The most interesting part here is that we started in the context of the `Location #2` and ended up in `Location #1` because of the `last` flag.

This is how it all works. And yes, if there is only one location, it will be used again (providing it matches the rewritten URI), but this time with the new (rewritten) URI. And yes, it is possible to cause an infinite loop with an unfortunate configuration. Although Nginx will detect and interrupt it after 10 cycles or so.

P.S. If you are wondering about `Rewrite rule #4`, in this configuration it is a "dead directive". It will never be executed.

Comment: This must be the clearest and most descriptive way I've ever seen of rewrite rules explained. Thank you!